# How make a user login with the url dashboard?username=xyz

Tags: php, user-management

I am a PHP beginner. I managed to create a user registration/signup system which leads to a dashboard panel. But I am not able to make the URL look like http://example.com/dashboard?username=xyz

Here is my checklogin code. Please help me out.

```
<?php 
include "config.php"; 
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))  
{  


echo  "<script>location.href='logindo.php?success=yes'</script>";


 }  
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))  
{  
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));  

$checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'");  

if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)  
{  
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);  
    $email = $row['EmailAddress'];  

    $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;  
    $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;  
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;  

    echo "<h1>Success</h1>";  
    echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";  
  echo  "<script>location.href='logindo.php?success=yes'</script>";
  } 



         else  
        {  

          echo  "<script>location.href='logindo.php?error=yes'</script>";
        }  
  }  


  else  
  {   
 }
  ?>
   <?php if($_GET['error'] == 'yes')
      {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
    echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"user_login.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>"; 
      }
      ?>

      <?php if($_GET['success'] == 'yes')
      {


   header('Location: /im/dashboard/');
      }
      ?>


 <?php if($_GET['error1'] == 'yes')
      {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
    echo "<p>Sorry, one ore more required fields were left empty. Please <a href=\"user_login.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>"; 
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)).

Comment: And SQL-escaping data before hashing it is **bad**.

Comment: can you please provide me the correct method? or any link to some tutorials which teach the right method? thnx

Comment: Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Where do you want that special URL? BTW, your `logindo.php?success=yes` is easy to replicate.

Comment: To make urls like this: `dashboard?username=xyz`, you need to use `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @Bhorer_Alo: No need for mod_rewrite, just create and accept query parameters.

Comment: an example script would be much appreciated, thank you every one for you advises. I am just a beginner...

Answer (score -1):

In order to use "dashboard?..." as your url, you'll need to utilise a method called Friendly URLS. This is simple enough, but you need access to your apache set up. Take a look at this answer for mod_rewrite help: [apache-mod-rewrite-friendly-urls-with-corresponding-301-redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376698/apache-mod-rewrite-friendly-urls-with-corresponding-301-redirects)

This will give you an idea of how this works. I've also found that some times, you'll have to use ForceType declarations in apache also. A quick google search will help with that, and who knows, you may not need it! Brush up on mod_rewrite first, and see what happens! HTH!

Comment: Rewriting URL's is not necessary for accepting a simple GET parameter.